# How to turn off "Use wireless networks" in Location and security in Android settings programatically?

Tags: android, android-wireless

I made an app which is need wireless networks for Location Manager.
If the user starts the app, a dialog will shown saying "Please turn on wireless networks for better location place"

If the user decides to turn it on, it will turned on forever, i mean it wont turn off if the user exits my app, and this thing is not a battery saver if you know what i mean.

How can i turn it off programatically on onStop() for example?

This option is located in Settings > Location and security > Use wireless networks (on/off)

Comment: I dont think apps have direct access to phone settings as that can be easily misused. It's the users responsibility to close things he doesnt need anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i turn it off programatically on onStop() for example?

You cannot change this programmatically.